# Check an element existence in table rows via jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a `table` tag on my page. I'm adding dynamically a new set of rows, where some of them can contain a `<button class="btn btn-primary"></button>` tag. I'm wondering, how to check the information via JQuery, if that table contains any rows with that button ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just try:

```
var buttons = $table.find('.btn.btn-primary');
var buttonExists = buttons.length > 0;
```

Table has to be a jQuery object containing your table.

Comment: simple as it should be ;) Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

You can use `length` to check the existence of an element. Try this:

```
var buttonExists = $("table .btn-primary").length != 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($('tr:contains(".btn")')){
  alert('has button')
}
```